# Switch statement to evaluate string input C++

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

I am working with a user entered string input and I need to use switch-statements to evaluate each of the entered input. My code below currently evaluates a users string input and looks to see if it is a upper case, number, or special character using ASCII codes. I am now sure how switch-statements work and how I could change an If statement to a switch-statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++) //for loop used to check the rules of the password inputted by the user
{
  cout << "Testing for upper case characters..." << endl; //displays the cout
  tmpi=(int) str1[i]; //stoi function making the string input an integer
  if ((tmpi >= 65) && (tmpi <= 90)) //checks if there are two upper case characters in the string
    {
      cout << "Found an uppercase" << endl;
      uppercnt++; //adds to the counter of upper case
      state++;
      cout << "Now in state q" << state << "..." << endl;
      continue;
    }
  cout << "Testing for digits..." << endl;
  if(tmpi >= 48 && tmpi <= 57) //checks if there are two digits in the string
    {
      cout << "Found a digit" << endl;
      digitcnt++; //adds to the counter of digit
      state++;
      cout << "Now in state q" << state << "..." << endl;
      continue;
    }
  cout << "Testing for special characters..." << endl;
  if(tmpi >= 33 && tmpi <= 47 || tmpi >= 58 && tmpi <= 64 || tmpi >= 91 && tmpi <= 96 || tmpi >= 123 && tmpi <= 126) //checks if there are special characters
    {
      cout << "Found a special char" << endl;
      speccnt++; //adds to the counter of special character
      state++;
      cout << "Now in state q" << state << "..." << endl;
      continue;
    }
  cout << "Character entered was a lower case" << endl;
  state++;
  cout << "Now in state q" << state << "..." << endl;
} //end for loop
```

Any advice or examples would help out, thanks.

Comment: Any input or direction or links would help out I have not used switch-statements very much and I am not 100% sure how they work.

Comment: You really should read [ask].

Comment: @dandan78 first time posting a quest, what should I change to make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if perfomance not an issue, I just would use `std::count_if`:

```
int upps = std::count_if( pass.begin(), pass.end(), isupper );
int digs = std::count_if( pass.begin(), pass.end(), isdigit );
```

working example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/IYUm3K)

Comment: In this example, is "isupper" part of the algorithm library?

Comment: Also would I be able to do something similar to this for a special character?

Comment: you can find all functions here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha